# Is it possible to use Plastic SCM and Gluon on the same Project?

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

Is it possible for two people to work on the same repository, one using the Plastic SCM interface (the general one) and the other using the Gluon interface (the lightweight one)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! That's certainly possible and that's actually how most of Game Studios are working using Plastic SCM.

**Artists will use Gluon** as it's much simpler and allows you to select what you want to download.

**Developers will use Plastic SCM** (regular GUI) in order to take advance of the great features it brings.